# Boolean to yes/no

Tags: java, methods, boolean

I'm trying to make a method named loopquery with the following parameters:

```
/** create a method named loopquery()
 *   - that returns a boolean value
 *   - accepts no arguments
 *   - content:
 *       - declaration of a boolean variable initialized to false
 *       - an InputDialog that requests if you want to loopagain (y,n)and assigns the value to a string variable
 *       - converts the String variable to upper case
 *       - changes the value of the boolean variable to true if the string variable has a value of "Y"
 *       - returns the value of the boolean variable  
*/
```

Below is what  have towards it, but I think i'm missing quite a bit. Is there anyone that can help me satisfy all the requirements above? Heres my vomit code

```
private static void loopquery() {
    String loopquery;
    boolean loopagain = true;

    loopquery = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Another table (y.n)", 
                          "Again?", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

    loopquery = loopquery.toUpperCase();
}
```

Comment: in short, though this won't be valid code: `if (loopquery == "Y") { loopagain = true } else { loopagain = false}`

Comment: `String s="no"; if(boolean) s="yes";`, as the title asks.

Comment: `that returns a boolean value` your method definition should probably be `boolean` then.

Comment: as per java bean naming conventions you should call your method "isLoopquery()"

Comment: If you're following @MarcB's code, make sure you use `if (loopquery.equals("Y"))`

Comment: "_declaration of a boolean variable initialized to false_" Change this `boolean loopagain = true;` to `boolean loopagain = false;`.

Answer (score 0):

For the requirements:

- changes the value of the boolean variable to true if the string variable has a value of "Y"
- returns the value of the boolean variable

You can add these lines at the end of your code to modify the boolean and return the value:

```
loopagain = loopquery.equals("Y");
return loopagain;
```

For the requirement:

- declaration of a boolean variable initialized to false

You initialize the boolean to true, replace this initialization:

```
boolean loopagain = true;
```

For this one:

```
boolean loopagain = false;
```

Note:

The standard notation for variables and methods in Java is CamelCase, to follow the standard naming convention, you should replace the names "loopquery" and "loopagain" for "loopQuery" and "loopAgain" respectively

Answer (score 0):

```
if(loopquery.equals("Y"))
   return true;
else if (loopquery.equals("N"))
   return false;
```

Remember you must change your method from void to boolean as you cannot return a value in a void method

Regards,

Kurtis

Answer (score 0):

```
private static boolean loopquery() {//change the return type to boolean
    String loopquery;
    boolean loopagain = false;//asked to have this initialized to false

    loopquery = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Another table (y.n)", 
                          "Again?", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

    if (loopquery.toUpperCase().equals("Y")) {
        loopagain = true;
    } 
    return loopagain;
}
```

You had the basic structure for the most part correct, but had discrepancies from the requirements that were asked of you:

- boolean initialized as `false`, you had it initialized as `true`
- it asked to have the boolean returned, you had a return type of `void`

How this works is if `loopagain` is `"Y"`, it will change loopagain to be `true`, otherwise it skips over and just returns loopagain as it's initialized value, `false`.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static boolean isLoopQuery()
{
    // Declaration of a boolean variable initialized to false
    boolean loopAgain = false;

    // An InputDialog that requests if you want to loopagain (y,n)and assigns the value to a string variable
    String loopQuery = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Another table (y.n)",
            "Again?", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

    // Converts the String variable to upper case
    loopQuery = loopQuery.toUpperCase();

    // Changes the value of the boolean variable to true if the string variable has a value of "Y"  
    if(loopQuery.equals("Y"));
    {
        loopAgain = true;
    }

    // returns the value of the boolean variable
    return loopAgain;
}
```

Hopefully this is a bit clear and adheres to each of your requirements.